# Clicking the like in the website should like in Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

from here i got that code and i placed in my website localhost but cannot able to see any change .Can anyone help me this
i got the code from here `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/`
 My code is like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/anicrave.shows" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: Did you include the SDK on your page? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: This is sdk right, i have already included `code`<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this link and add the references to your page.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

You're missing an essential part for FB-SDK in order to display the expected results.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```